# Jquery each() not working correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have some code that needs adjusting. I need the .play "rel" to be replaced with the .audio_player "id". There will be multiple "media" divs that will need to be gone through.

Here is the code

```
<div class="media">
    <div class="message_buttons">
        <li id="listen" class="play_button">
            <a class="play" rel="" href="AudioFile.mp3"> Listen </a>
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="audio_player" id="play1243">
        <audio controls="controls"></audio>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is the script I have so far. It seems to work with the first media div, but then makes every .play "rel" on the page the same as the first audio_player "id" and not the "id" in it's own div.

```
$.each($('.play'), function( index ) {
    //$(this).attr("rel", $(".audio_player").attr("id"));
    $(".play").attr("rel", $(".audio_player").attr("id"));
});
```

I commented-out another version that also works but gives the same result. Thank you guys so much for helping me get this far. I feel like I am really really close now. But can't get it that last little bit. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.play').each(function(){
   $(this).attr("rel",$(this).closest('.message_buttons').next('.audio_player').attr('id'));
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwebb/3RDPX/)

Answer (score 2):

Just run `each()` on the selector and then you can use the `this` context for each element found:

```
$('.play').each(function(i) {
    var id = $(this).parents('.media').find('.audio_player').attr('id');
    $(this).attr('rel', id);
});
```

Comment: Only problem with this is it will give the same 'audio_player' id each time.

Comment: Oh ok sorry, my solution was based on your code. I will fix it.

Comment: This solution still doesn't seem to work.  Check out my solution and working jsfiddle.

Comment: Thanks JesseB. I just changed it to something more simple. I actually didn't know about the `closest` selector. +1 for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".play").each(function() {
  $(this).attr("rel", $(".audio_player").attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this:

```
$('.play').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('rel', $(this).closest('.media').find('.audio_player').attr('id'));
});
```

Check out **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zQEvU/)** to see it in action.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.play').each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr('rel', $('.audio_player').get(index).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way

```
$.each($('.play'), function( index ) {
$(this).attr("rel",$(this).closest(".audio_player").attr("id"));
});
```

check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X35W5/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.play').each(function( index ) {
  $(this).attr("rel", $(this).closest('.media').find('.audio_player').attr('id'));
});
```